# Calling notifyDataSetChanged in my onFocusChangedListener causes focus to freak out in my ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, android-view

I have a ListView which has multiple EditTexts per item. When I change an EditText on one item, I'd like it to affect the text on the next item. I'm using an `onFocusChanged` listener and I can successfully update the underlying data, but My actual focus is lost (and my cursor ends up in weird places). Please review my code and offer any insight. I've been banging my head about this for a while.

Note:

- I am not recycling items using a holder, as this was giving me odd behavior and my performance is not suffering. Every time I've tried re-enabling the recycling, things get messier.
- I have overriden `hasStableIds` to return `true`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Assigning the Listener:

```
MyFocusChangeListener myFocusListener = new MyFocusChangeListener(myItem, position);
holder.et_min.setOnFocusChangeListener(myFocusListener);
```

Defining the Listener:

```
private class MyFocusChangeListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{
  private EditText et;
  private EditText curView;
  private ScaleItem item;
  private Integer pos;

  public MyFocusChangeListener(ScaleItem item, Integer pos){
      this.item = item;
      this.pos = pos;
  }

  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
      if(!hasFocus){ 
          et = (EditText) v;

          System.out.println("EditText lost focus on row:  " + et.getText().toString() + "   et id: " + et.getId()); 
          if(pos < data.size()){
            data.get(pos + 1).setMax(Double.valueOf(et.getText().toString()));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("Updated dataset and called notifyDataSetChanged()");
          } 
      } else {
          et = (EditText) v;
          if(et != null)
              System.out.println("EditText just RECEIVED focus on row : " + et.getText().toString() + "   et id: " + et.getId());
    }
 }
```

}

This is the console output I get, if I enter the activity, click field A, and then click field B.

[image]

Notice:

- Each EditText (regardless of row) has the same ID (I think this is expected)
- The *only* change I'm making is to the underlying data. In fact, I have the same issue if I change nothing but call `notifyDataSetChanged`.
- The target field loses focus, I've no idea why.

**TL;DR** - Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my `onFocusChangedListener` causes focus to freak out in my `ListView`.

See? The cursor is drunk.
[image]

Comment: Why do you need notifyDataSetChanged at all? Retrieve and/or set the data directly (if it is within same layout/item). To "invalidate" whole row use the getAdapter getView with corresponding (if visible) row view  (ListView getFirstVisiblePosition... getChildAt etc) (when action in one row modifies data in other row). Though might not work: I do set TextViews (and data) within same row when EditText changes.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Comment: @Deucalion, you were absolutely right about using `getFirstVisiblePosition` and `getChildAt`. I ended up abandoning the ListView completely, but if you post as an answer to how to update views, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you focus a `EditText` in `ListView` get position value, after updating `ListView` redrawn and automatically it will select last position.

Step 1:

```
if (_Curserposition == position) {
    holder.textViewStake.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    //holder.textViewStake.clearFocus();
    holder.textViewStake.requestFocus();
    holder.textViewStake.setSelection(holder.textViewStake.getText().toString().length());
}
```

Step 2:

```
holder.textViewStake.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        _Curserposition = position;
        Log.d(">>>", "setOnFocusChangeListener" + _Curserposition);
        /*  
        //showVirtualKeyboard(con_text, v);
        // holder.textViewStake.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activityContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (hasFocus) {
            imm.showSoftInput(holder.textViewStake, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        } else {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.textViewStake.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }*/
    }
});
```

Step 3:

```
holder.textViewStake.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        betlist_view.setFocusable(false);
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            try {
                if (Integer.parseInt(holder.textViewStake.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                    int _Stackamt = Integer.parseInt(holder.textViewStake.getText().toString());
                    int _picknumber = arrayDailyGameDrawList.get(position).getID();
                    //Log.d(">>>", "_picknumber" + position + "-" + arrayDailyGameDrawList.get(position).getBetNumberID() + "-" + Common.DrawId + "-" + _Stackamt + "-" + arrayDailyGameDrawList.get(position).getBetNumberID());
                    AddUpdateDailyGameNumberIntoList(
                        position, 
                        2, 
                        arrayDailyGameDrawList.get(position).getBetNumberID(), 
                        Common.DrawId, 
                        _Stackamt, 
                        arrayDailyGameDrawList.get(position).getBetNumberID()
                    );

                    /*  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    }, 3000);*/
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {
            holder.textViewStake.setText("0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```